# Bone rig doesn't work?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I'm trying to rig a model I have, but when I add the skeleton, I pose and it glitches.
An arm also pulls the stomach, 1 leg bone will pull both legs, and the head will pull the body too. I don't know what to do!
(BTW I used Automatic Weights, with Envlope Weights it's a whole different problem.)

Comment: Sounds like automatic weights didn't work very well with your model. That often happens when the rest pose for weighting is inappropriate for generating automatic weights. Try fixing weights manually. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0VS0IVylzg

Answer (score 1):

Use weight paint mode in order to fix the geometry effected by the bones.

Select the mesh and you can change to weight paint mode by pressing CTRL + TAB.

Use CTRL + Right Click to select bones. You will see colors ranging from Red (a weight of 1) to Blue (a weight of 0). A weight of 1 means the geometry moves with the bone and a weight of 0 means the geometry is not affected by the bone. You can use the subtract brush to remove weight from geometry you do not want the bone to affect.

You can learn more about weight paint mode here: http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/weight_paint.html

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today. I've been doing rigs for quite some time and a very simply armature deform was completely mucked up. It was pulling both legs, parts of the body etc just like the op.

It turned out a modifier that was applied(boolean in my case) was not correctly done even though it looked fine. I undid all the way to that point and reset the armature and it worked.

Perhaps in your case it was something similar. Undo and try that.